# Long vs Integer, long vs int, what to use and when?

Tags: java, types, numbers

Sometimes I see API's using `long` or `Long` or `int` or `Integer`, and I can't figure how the decision is made for that?

When should I choose what?

Answer (score 229, accepted):

`Long` is the `Object` form of `long`, and `Integer` is the object form of `int`.

The `long` uses [64 bits](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing). The `int` uses 32 bits, and so can only hold numbers up to ±2 billion (-2<sup>31</sup> to +2<sup>31</sup>-1).

You should use `long` and `int`, except where you need to make use of methods inherited from `Object`, such as `hashcode`. `Java.util.collections` methods usually use the boxed (`Object`-wrapped) versions, because they need to work for any `Object`, and a primitive type, like `int` or `long`, is not an `Object`.

Another difference is that `long` and `int` are *pass-by-value*, whereas `Long` and `Integer` are *pass-by-reference value*, like all non-primitive Java types. So if it were possible to modify a `Long` or `Integer` (it's not, they're immutable without using JNI code), there would be another reason to use one over the other.

A final difference is that a `Long` or `Integer` could be `null`.

Comment: @Borealid, this is so wrong, Java is always pass by value, there is nothing such as pass by reference in Java.

Comment: Uh huh? Okay, let's explore the idea that Java never passes a reference. If I call a function giving it an int[2], and then inside the function I change the value held in the first element of that array, will the function's caller see that change? Yes? Well that's because what was passed to the function wasn't the values in the array, but rather a reference to those values. "Pass by value" means the actual data themselves are being copied around with no indirection. Whomever taught you that Java was pass-by-value did you a disservice.

Comment: @Borealid you are incorrect, the value is changed because a new copy of the reference to the array was created, that is why whoever is calling the function will see the change, this is still pass by value. I can't believe you say that there is pass by reference in Java. You never pass the original reference to the function.

Comment: In a theoretical world where Java behaved completely differently from how it actually does, and passing an object or array to a function resulted in a totally separate copy (where modifications inside the function weren't reflected to callers at all), how would you then describe the language? Keeping in mind that what we're talking about is completely not what Java actually does.

Comment: @DiegoRamos is right. Java is always pass by value, the confusion is created because the value when non primitive is a memory reference, static swapping does not work in java, more details here: https://www.journaldev.com/3884/java-is-pass-by-value-and-not-pass-by-reference

Comment: Actually, java is "pass by value" only: a *reference* to an object will be passed **by value**, as a function argument (so references are copied into the stack frame of callees). The actual data referred to by a reference is never implicitly copied; merely the reference to it is.

Comment: Let's say I have a function `foo(x)`. I invoke it by calling `foo(my_arr)`, and the function contains the lines `x[1]=5; x=[];`. If the language uses "pass by value" semantics, the _value_ of the array would be copied -  not just the reference - and the caller would see no change to `my_arr`. If it uses "pass by reference" semantics, then after the call, `my_arr` would be empty. If the language uses "pass by reference value" semantics, the caller would see a `my_arr` with its second element set to `5`. Let's not come up with wording that makes two of these scenarios be called the same thing.

Comment: Can anyone honestly 100% believe that any programming language be pass by value only? Passing by value, for some kind of structure anyway, is where the caller allocates onto the stack a new copy of the object prior to the function call. The caller then performs the usual function call semantics, passing the address of the "pre-allocated" and duplicated structure. The callee now has access to their own copy, or to a "pass by value" structure using the address it was given. It's up to the Callee to deallocate this structure and to fix the stack for the caller on return, to avoid a memory leak.

Comment: You can incorrectly state those steps as "pass by reference," but if you do, and you initiate a call to an external library function elsewhere with the callee expecting "pass by value" semantics, passing the address to your caller's structure. Your caller's structure will be deallocated on return, and there will be no structure at all on the return back to the caller.
-Pass by Value duplicates the elements of Struct A to a new location of Struct B.
-Pass by Reference simply uses the location of Struct A.
No matter what! They all pass a memory location which can fit inside a register.

Comment: I think I described, above your comment, three different ways that passing an array can behave.

Comment: Correction, Class forms not Object forms so Long is the Class form of long, and Integer is the Class form form of int

Comment: MIcrosoft calls long a 32 bit integer, at least for excel, which is the most it can handle.

Comment: Java is not pass-by-reference because when you create `bla = new Cat()` and pass it as the parameter `x` in a function, you can modify the outside object with `x.changeName()` because `x` contains a copy of the reference to the same object. But if you do `x = new Dog()`, `x` now references the newly created `Dog` inside the function, while `bla` outside the function still contains the `Cat`. In pass-by-reference languages, `x = new Dog()` would change the outside `bla` to point to a `Dog`. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value

Comment: @Borealid you said there are 3 types of passing an array, but the "pass by value" where the whole Array content is copied in languages where the Array is an Object *does not exist*. You have to make an array copy yourself. If you understand what the names pass-by-value and pass-by-reference mean and you understand which data types are primitive and which are Objects/Boxed (only the pointer to the Object is passed in pass-by-value and a pointer to this pointer in pass-by-reference), you can understand the semantics of pass-by-value and pass-by-reference for all primitive types and all Objects.

Comment: I think it's pretty funny that you say it's impossible for a programming language to copy an array for you. In C, if you pass a struct to a function, you get a copy of the struct, no matter how much data is inside it. That's because C is a pass-by-value language.

Java doesn't choose to do that. Java _could_ do that. But it doesn't. Instead, when you try to pass an Object to a function, Java copies the reference (creating a new reference) but leaves the original where it lies.

Comment: I specifically chose my sentence as "in languages where the Array is an Object", so as not to include languages where it can be a primitive kind of value like C and Go. What I mean by Object is maybe a bit Java specific, I mean a data type where the main data is only pointed to. But Boxed (being an Object) or primitive is a common distinction and people expect different semantics when passing it to a function because of the very issue we discuss where either the same Object is changed or a copy of the primitive data is changed when `thing.a = 5` is executed inside the function.

Comment: In C++, you mostly pass an Object by passing a pointer to the Object cause that is the most useful. You could pass the Object and a copy would be made and in that sense Java can only pass the Object by passing the reference and that is the behaviour you are talking about: It's not possible to pass an Object type as a value of the Object, you have to copy it yourself for that. The practical meaning of pass-by-value and pass-by-reference changes in a weird way if it's an Object not a primitive, but if you know that distinction, it's still useful to think of it being pass-by-value only in Java.

Comment: It's useful cause pass-by-value and pass-by-reference have specific meanings in programming languages and if s.o. tells you a language is pass-by-value and which data types are primitive and boxed / pointers to the actual data, then you can deduce every behaviour of passing things you might wonder about, and that's pretty useful. Saying Java is "pass-by-reference for Objects" is indeed a useful simplification of the underlying mechanism if you want to understand the weird difference between passing an Object and primitive when thinking that it should all be the typical pass-by-value behavior.

Comment: In Go, you can decide if you want to pass the struct as a primitive type or a pointer to it if you want to modify it in the function or it is too big and you want to pass a only a pointer for performance reasons. In Java, it's just not that transparent that you always pass a pointer to the object underneath the hood. But knowing Go is pass-by-value and then knowing you can pass pointers or structs directly, it's easy to understand the possible semantics. For Java, you "just" need to know that passing an Object / Boxed type is always passing a pointer, then everything else makes sense again.

Comment: But I think it would be more confusing to say "In Go, if you pass the pointer to the struct, then Go passes by reference and if not it passes by value", because the way Go calls the function and copies or not copies the arguments didn't change internally. The way a function is called didn't fundamentally change, and the true pass-by-reference calling of a function with the way the arguments are passed is fundamentally different on that level.

Comment: True pass-by-reference is another level of indirection more. It's the question of: Can I assign a new value inside a function and have it be reflected outside the function? And that's only possible if you pass a reference to the same outside variable (it gives the same power as being able to access that outside variable name like `outsideName = ...`) and can then totally change what this outside variable represents from inside the function.

Answer (score 34):

- By default use an `int`, when holding numbers.
- If the range of `int` is too small, use a `long`
- If the range of `long` is too small, use `BigInteger`
- If you need to handle your numbers as object (for example when putting them into a `Collection`, handling `null`, ...) use `Integer`/`Long` instead

Answer (score 32):

There are a couple of things you can't do with a primitive type:

- Have a `null` value
- synchronize on them
- Use them as type parameter for a generic class, and related to that:
- Pass them to an API that works with `Object`s

Unless you need any of those, you should prefer primitive types, since they require less memory.

Answer (score 20):

#### **Integer** is a signed 32 bit integer type

- Denoted as **`Int`**
- Size  = **`32 bits (4byte)`**
- Can hold integers of range **`-2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647`**
- default value is **0**

### **Long** is a signed 64 bit integer type

- Denoted as **`Long`**
- Size  = **`64 bits (8byte)`**
- Can hold integers of range **`-9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807`**
- default value is **0L**

If your usage of a variable falls in the 32 bit range, use `Int`, else use `long`. Usually long is used for scientific computations and stuff like that need much accuracy. (eg. value of pi).

> **An example of choosing one over the other is YouTube's case.** They first defined video view counter as an `int` which was overflowed when more than 2,147,483,647 views where received to a popular video. Since an `Int` counter cannot store any value more than than its range, YouTube changed the counter to a 64 bit variable and now can count up to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 views. Understand your data and choose the type which fits, as **64 bit variable will take double the memory than a 32 bit variable.**

Comment: Well explained using `youtube views` example.

Answer (score 15):

An `int` is a 32-bit integer; a `long` is a 64-bit integer. Which one to use depends on how large the numbers are that you expect to work with.

`int` and `long` are primitive types, while `Integer` and `Long` are objects. Primitive types are more efficient, but sometimes you need to use objects; for example, Java's collection classes can only work with objects, so if you need a list of integers you have to make it a `List<Integer>`, for example (you can't use `int` in a `List` directly).

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to using a very long number that may exceed 32 bits to represent, you may use long to make sure that you'll not have strange behavior.

From Java 5 you can use in-boxing and out-boxing features to make the use of int and Integer completely the same. It means that you can do :

```
int myInt = new Integer(11);
Integer myInt2 = myInt;
```

The in and out boxing allow you to switch between int and Integer without any additional conversion (same for `Long`,`Double`,`Short` too)

You may use `int` all the time, but `Integer` contains some helper methods that can help you to do some complex operations with integers (such as `Integer.parseInt(String)` )

Answer (score 0):

a) object Class "Long" versus primitive type "long". (At least in Java)

b) There are different (even unclear) memory-sizes of the primitive types:

Java - all clear: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

- byte, char .. 1B .. 8b
- short int .. 2B .. 16b
- int .. .. .. .. 4B .. 32b
- long int  .. 8B .. 64b

C .. just mess: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types

- short .. .. 16b
- int .. .. .. 16b ... wtf?!?!
- long .. .. 32b
- long long .. 64b .. mess! :-/

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which is about the difference between Long and long etc.

Comment: No, it does not explicitly answer it, not explicitly saying the difference between a primitive types vs. data type objects, indeed @GreenAsJade, because the question here above does not state any specific language. So I provided a comparison - so everybody can check the difference. (from the hard data, as provided)

Comment: The question stated Java.