# How to take input in ArrayList in java when number of values is not a constant?

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to take input For example:

> 550
>   234234
>   874982634
>   3487239482349

The length of the input is not fixed and i want to take input in the array list of java.

```
ArrayList<Integer> basicpg = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Comment: Good luck, you can do it! Try to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) when you have some time.

Comment: `basicpg.add("550 234234 874982634 3487239482349")`.

Comment: Do you want to store your value as single entry or do you want to save each number separately?

Comment: User404 is correct: it sounds like you pretty much understand the problem, and basically have the solution.  Since the #/items is variable, you want a "List" (e.g. ArrayList).  So I guess your question is "How do I input the items?".  A: read from System.in, e.g. `Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);`.  Here are a couple of approaches: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488072/reading-in-from-system-in-java

Comment: @ak47_kalani follow [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5857812/long-vs-integer-long-vs-int-what-to-use-and-when)

Comment: Actually I want to take input from the user for example case1-550 case2-3249 case3-73408 , the length of the input is not fixed , i want to add it to array list but the length is not fixed and in one run only one input is fed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
ArrayList<Integer> basicpg = new ArrayList<Integer>();
String input;
while((input = br.readLine()) != null && input.length() != 0)
{
    basicpg.add(Integer.parseInt(input));
}
```

[image: 1st case]
If they are space seperated, use `.split()`

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String input = br.readLine();
String[] tokens = input.split(" ");
List<String> wordList = Arrays.asList(tokens);
```

[image]

Comment: Actually I want to take input from the user for example case1-550 case2-3249 case3-73408 , the length of the input is not fixed , i want to add it to array list but the length is not fixed and in one run only one input is fed

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList<Long> basicpg = new ArrayList<Long>();
basicpg.add(550);
basicpg.add(234234);
basicpg.add(874982634);
basicpg.add(3487239482349);
```

If the `Integer` length is too long you might want to change it to `Long`.
Integer has a limit & since you are not sure as to what might be the length of the input integer. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15004944/max-value-of-integer), or you can put a condition wherein the input integer should be `<=Integer.MAX_VALUE`

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following code snippet -

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
ArrayList<Integer> basicpg = new ArrayList<Integer>();

while(s.hasNexInt()){

 Integer i = s.nextInt();
 basicpg.add(i);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

why not just split the input string with space and add it in a loop?

```
String s = "550 234234 874982634 3487239482349"
ArrayList<Integer> basicpg = new ArrayList<>();
for(ss: s.split()){
    try{
       Integer i = Integer.parseInt(ss);
       basicpg.add(i);
    }catch(Exception e){
       e.printStackTrace();
       contine;
    }
}
```